# Is there any way to use a Google-managed SSL certificate when using Google Cloud CDN?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, cdn

This would be similar to AWS Cloudfront which can use a certificate that is generated by AWS for you.

Is there anything like that here?

This would be mostly for cost or ease of use reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Load balancers now support GCP managed certificates that are similar to those used by App Engine (Lets Encrypt certificates).  [The feature is tagged as beta until the end of 2019](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Google Cloud Platform allows generating a self-signed SSL certificate for testing purposes only, see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates#gettingakeyandcertificate), however, for production purposes you should get real certificate from a Certificate Authority.

The possibility to have this feature in GCP similar to AWS Certificate Manager will be launched in a near future, even though there is no Estimated time of arrival for the moment. The evolution of this feature request can be tracked [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900617).

Comment: FYI this is there now, we were able to spin up a LB with a Google Managed Certificate